# Logic Circuit Completely Failing (Cue Lights System)

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, failure

I have been working on a circuit the details of which are below. Today I finally got round to finishing and testing it. Guess what! It failed... I don't know if this is the place for this but would appreciate any help. 
The circuit is for a theatre 'cue lights' system. The intended functionality of which is described below.

---

Below is my schematic. NB: An XLR cable connects the two connectors at the bottom right.
[image: Schematic]

---

The intended functionality is as described below:
[image: Intended functionality]

---

The initial testing reported very different results:
*note that these results are very intermittent. at one point the system locked up with the LEDs on and whatever buttons I pressed they remained on.*
[image: Actual functionality]

---

If you want me to try and certain combinations or replacing components or changing wiring let me know and feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: Do you have power supply bypass capacitors (0.1 uF between Vcc and Ground), particularly on the flip-flops.  Please re-draw the schematic using only vertical and horizontal lines as much as possible, with no wires passing through components.  Unused IC sections should be placed outside the active circuit to reduce confusion.  What are the two four-terminal boxes near the lower right of the drawing - can't make out any part number.

Comment: https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/blog/top-10-tips-draw-next-schematic-design-like-pro/

Comment: do you mean decoupling capacitors? those are the XLR connectors in the bottom right. I will try and find time to redraw the schematic tommorow.

Comment: No those 4 terminal boxes are solid state relays. ASSR-1228-002E

Comment: Calling that a schematic is a stretch.  You have unused gates.  Wires passing through components.  Power rails everywhere.  All wires are green.  Fuzzy text.  Too much miscellaneous information to process.  State Table listed twice.  How did you determine the logic for  your state machine (assuming it is a state machine)?  TTL logic floats high, but I'd pull Clear and Preset to VCC on your 74LS74's.  About the best suggestion I can give is to edit you question and create a legitimate schematic using the schematic editor.

Comment: For example, IC6A (74ALS08 AND) pin 3 (Output) looks like it is connected to VCC, which makes no sense.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat: U6 pin 3 also appears to be connected to Ground, depending on which wire you follow.  Must be wires overlaid in many places - generally a totally incomprehensible drawing - no point trying to understand it until it is re-drawn in a clear manner.

Comment: Look, about the schematic, its not great because it was just for me. I'll redraw it sometime soon. The two state tables are completely different. You would know that if you read the whole post. One is intended one is what happened.

Comment: Even if the schematic was just for you, it isn't now. Also, a clear, clean, organized, meaningful schematic will be a lot easier read and troubleshoot in the future (for you or someone else). So, moral of the story is always try to make a good schematic.  =-D

Comment: My software, autodesk eagle doesn't allow coloured nets. If you want I can provide the schematic file for you to take a closer look at. But aside from organising nets which I can't do now since I don't have time that's all I can really do.

Comment: Eagle is not exactly my tool of choice but it is capable of FAR better then that, just using the power and ground symbols would help to remove a lot of not very interesting rat lines. Question, how is pressing the standby ack button supposed to get back to the logic? Also, where are the LED current limiting series resistors? You have LS series logic with switches pulling UP? That stuff needs a fairly stiff pull down if that is going to work (And in fact you have no pull owns on the switches at all)!

Comment: Odds are you have switch bounce on the go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite apart from that dogs dinner that you call a schematic, that is possibly the most over done single channel cue light controller that I have ever seen.

I mean, gods man, not only is it a single channel setup with no master controls (which makes it painful to use if you have more then one cue to fire at a given time), but it is madly complex.

Here is a version I did (Does not quite work the same way, but it is close).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZvZpL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 4 switches at the left are the master switches and provide two standby and two 'go' groups, these switches are centre off with a latching position when moved up and a momentary action when pressed down.

The per channel cue switches are two position, depending on which master you wish to assign to, and are centre off.

When standby is activated the standby indicator on the stage managers console (which is in series with the standby lamp on the outstation) flashes because both are in series with the flashing LED hidden inside the outstation. Pressing the acknowledge button on the outstation causes the small thyristor to trigger which then holds the 'acknowledge' on solid until the cue is cleared from the stage managers console.

All LEDS are series circuits between the outstation and the console so that broken wiring may be easily identified.

As I am clearly never going to hear the end of this toy project: [image: Schematic]

You will notice that this is actually readable, and that it is easy to follow what is happening.

The 4013 has power and ground pins that will need to be connected to the appropriate places, and a 100nF ceramic capacitor should be placed across power and ground close to each 4013.

I could not be arsed to draw the logic for a set of master controls but they should be fairly obvious.

Comment: Sorry... which switches are standby and which are go?

Comment: It seems a bit over complicated (less so than mine, I know) why does there need to be a switch to switch between individual and master? Shouldn't master go just override the current cues that are standbyed?

Comment: The other thing I wanted was to be able to have push button functionality. That's part of the reasoning for the more complicated design. How could that be implemented into this? Just add flip-flops?

Comment: Say I want to "Standby LX, fly, motion control, and sound" and I know that I will be wanting to Go on LX and Flys at the same time, but motion and sound a few seconds later. So I ensure all the master switches (at the left) are off, and put the standby switches for Lx, flys and motion control and sound up, I put the go switches for lx and flys up, and the go switches for motion control and sound down. I get clearance and switch standby 1 up, lights start flashing until people ack the standby where they turn green, I fire the first by hitting GO on bus 1, and the second by hitting GO on bus 2.

Comment: Yea, suggest 4000 series set reset latches or 4013 and use the async set and clear because they will run from a 12V rail with pmos switches to drive the outputs, but actually most people like toggle switches for SM consoles.

Comment: So if those witches on the left are masters, where are the individual channel go and standby switches?

Comment: Two three position On-Off-On toggles (one for Standby, one for Go) in the middle of the diagram, connected to R2 and R3. These get repeated for however many channels of cue light you need for your installation.

Comment: More (or less) sophisticated switching schemes are possible obviously, the real magic in this thing being how the acknowledge button works in the outstation. Any cue light system should be designed to ensure so far as possible that a broken connection or unplugged out station will be obvious to the stage manager. A broken cue light is much less of a problem then a non obviously not working one. One refinement might be a set of direct 'go' buttons (one per channel) wired directly from 12V to R3, useful just make sure someone putting a script down cannot accidentally hit half a dozen.

Comment: Is there any chance you could knock up a schematic for buttons to toggle the master bus on the individual channel and buttons to toggle the bus states?

Comment: Is this some sort of academic project is is this something some venue actually needs? I ask because if it is for a venue then if you ask the stage management crew very likely the response will be "Keep it simple stupid". That job is quite stressful enough without adding potentially confusing logic that will glitch if there is a power issue. Set/reset latches (for debouncing the buttons), D type flipflops to hold the button state and pmos transistors to switch the power, easy, but IMHO pointless.

Comment: This is a personal project but will be used at my school for some performances

Comment: I have been speaking with the main SM and he is definitely for buttons.

Comment: So would you be able to help create said shcematic?

Comment: what is the point in having the on-off-momentary switches? instead of on-off

Comment: Sometimes a guy has two cues close together, press the toggle to momentary, release then a second or so later press it again to fire the second cue. Probably more useful for the go button then the standby. As I said, plenty of options in the switching, just depends on what your users want. I have seen single master systems where on-off-mom was used for the channel switches with the momentary position wired direct to the power bypassing the master (Press down to trigger a single cue immediately or latch up and fire the whole set from the master, something to be said for that).

Comment: Is there a high current version of the 4013 that can handle the circuit?

Comment: Nope, but there are many, many pmos mosfets that will handle the current easily and can be trivially controlled by a cmos output. You don't even need a driver if you make the supply for the flipflop equal to the source voltage of the pmos transistor, and at 12V you don't need the 'logic level' ones, the standard sort will do just fine.

Comment: Do you have any links to an example circuit with the pmos and d-flip flop

Comment: Would this bjt work instead of the mosfet? http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2303892.pdf?_ga=2.207661394.1549168898.1547504815-784093195.1546026081&_gac=1.16789835.1547064371.Cj0KCQiA1NbhBRCBARIsAKOTmUtU27_VR6Bh-IYAYTYEYnuBW_V15qbrEtRfxguYNDjPjXWbGMJW2OIaAqH8EALw_wcB

Comment: Not reliably, minimum Hfe is rather low and the 4000 series are not well known for having outputs capable of sourcing much current (which is why I chose to use a p channel mosfet). I have added a schematic of a flipflop version, to which teacher should I go for a grade?

Comment: What sort of component then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88269/discussion-between-dan-mills-and-615283).